# How to draw random simple closed smooth curves but with the same perimeter?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, metapost, asymptote

I want to draw some random simple smooth closed curves. Each  smooth curve must have the same perimeter but different area.
See the following figure to illustrate what I meant clearly.  Each smooth curve is assumed to have the same perimeter.

[image]

How to do this with PSTricks (preferred) or TikZ or Metapost or Asymptote?

The following template is provided to save your time.

```
\documentclass{pstricks,border=12pt,12pt}

\begin{document}
\psLoop{10}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Closed curves? like circles, eclipses, or strings with different numbers of bends?

Comment: @Ryan: Any closed curve without self-intersection. :-)

Comment: I'm curious -- what's the application, here?  I can think of a few in topology (for teaching purposes), but I'm curious about what you have in mind :)

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: @SeanAllred: I just want to make an illustration for teaching calculus of variation by which we solve a famous problem (about searching for a simple closed smooth curve with the largest area). :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution, which uses pst-intersect's ability to save a generic path. So, first a random path is generated (how is pretty much arbitrary), then it is loaded, its path length is calculated and then it is redrawn with scaled coordinates:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-intersect}
\makeatletter
\def\SaveRandomPath{%
  \pssavepath[linestyle=none, arrows=-,ArrowInside=-]{A}{%
    \moveto(! /@S Rand 1.5 mul def @S Rand mul 1 add 0 PtoC 2 copy /@Y ED /@X ED)
    \psparametricplot[plotpoints=35]{10}{350}{@S Rand mul 1 add t Rand 0.5 sub 5 mul add PtoC}%
    \lineto(!@X @Y)
  }%
}%
\def\TraceAndScaleCurve{\pst@object{TraceAndScaleCurve}}%
\def\TraceAndScaleCurve@i#1{%
  \begin@OpenObj
    \addto@pscode{%
      \pst@intersectdict
      \PIT@name{A} -1 -1
    {\psk@plotpoints exch
      \txFunc@BezierCurve
      \ifshowpoints \txFunc@BezierShowPoints \else pop \fi
    } 4 copy
    TraceCurveOrPath PathLength #1 div 
    dup 1 exch div dup scale 5 1 roll 
    newpath TraceCurveOrPath dup scale
  }%
  \end@OpenObj
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\multido{\i=-4+2}{5}{%
  \multido{\ii=-4+2}{5}{%
    \SaveRandomPath
    \rput(\i,\ii){\TraceAndScaleCurve{150}}}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I haven't counted the number of keystrokes, but I thought I make it clearer rather than short and cryptic ;)

[image]

To make it smoother, one can tweak the parameters and use e.g. `plotstyle=cspline`, which gives results like

[image]

Comment: Could you make it look as smooth as the metapost version?

Comment: Yes, use e.g. `plotstyle=cspline`. This leaves you a possible sharp edge only where the curve is closed.

Comment: Should be `\begin@ClosedObj ... \end@ClosedObj`

Comment: I guess your starting point is the same as the ending point so there is always one cusp. The starting point should be different from the ending point to remove such a cusp. Am I correct?

Comment: No, the cspline plotstyle simply cannot handle periodic boundaries: the curvatures of the curve start and curve end should depend on each other, but they don't.

Answer (score 18):

Here's a Metapost effort.

[image]

The shapes above are all scaled to the same desired length, and show increasing levels of randomness from black to red.  Here's the code:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);
desired_length = 500;
N = 30;
r = 50;

path shape;
for s=0 step 1 until 11:
  shape := (r,0)
          for i=1 upto N-1: .. (r+s*normaldeviate,0) rotated (i/N*360) endfor
          .. cycle;
  shape := shape scaled (desired_length/arclength shape);
  draw shape shifted (4*((s*r) mod 200), 4r*floor((s*r)/200)) withcolor (s/12)[black,red];
endfor

endfig;
end.
```

Comment: Love it because of the fewest number of keystrokes. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

If I got the sums right then this calculates the length of each curve, given the length it then redraws the path, scaling everything so the length equals your target length.

[image]

```
/getpathlength
{flattenpath
{exch dup /startx exch def
 exch dup /starty exch def
 /currentx startx  def
 /currenty starty  def
 /currentlength 0 def
 moveto}
{exch dup /newx exch def
 exch dup /newy exch def
 /currentlength
 currentlength
 newx currentx sub dup mul
 newy currenty sub dup mul
 add
 sqrt
 add
 def
 /currentx newx def
 /currenty newy def
 lineto}
{(curve) == curveto}
{/currentlength
 currentlength
 startx currentx sub dup mul
 starty currenty sub dup mul
 add
 sqrt
 add
 def
 closepath
}
pathforall}
def


/redopath
{
{newpath starty sub pathscale mul starty add exch
         startx sub pathscale mul startx add exch moveto}
{        starty sub pathscale mul starty add exch
         startx sub pathscale mul startx add exch  lineto}
{(curveto) ==}
{closepath}
pathforall
}
def

/scalepathto
{
getpathlength
/pathscale exch 
currentlength div def
redopath
stroke}
def

newpath
100 200 moveto
10 10 rlineto
2 20 rlineto
30 -50  60 100 -100 0 rcurveto
closepath
400 scalepathto






newpath
200 400 moveto
20 20 rlineto
4 40 rlineto
60 -100  120 200 -200 0 rcurveto
closepath
400 scalepathto

newpath
300 500 moveto
20 10 rlineto
20 20 rlineto
4 40 rlineto
20 20  40 100 60 10 rcurveto
20 -20  40 -30 10 -60 rcurveto
closepath
400 scalepathto

newpath
400 400 20 0 360 arc
400 scalepathto


newpath
400 100 40 0 360 arc
400 scalepathto




showpage


quit
```

Comment: Are all the curves above smooth? :-)

Comment: @Whoiscrazyfirst You above all should know to define `smooth` if you mean it so ;-)

Comment: @Whoiscrazyfirst well after flatternpath they're piecewise linear so it depends how you define smooth:-)  but the point is that you can put `400 scalepathto` after any closed path, it doesn't have to be smooth or non-intersecting, so it therefore applies to smooth non-intersecting paths if you choose to apply it to those.

Answer (score 5):

Please find a not perfect solution with Asymptote. Since the points are randomly generated it is not easy to have a non-intersecting path. So I remember some hull computation with some parameters. You can find it http://git.piprime.fr/?p=asymptote/pi-packages.git;a=blob;f=hull_pi.asy;hb=HEAD and some examples are on http://www.piprime.fr/developpeur/asymptote/unofficial-packages-asy/hull_pi_asy/.
I have to admit that I do not understand very well all the parameters but you can obtain some non convex path.  Each path is scaled to obtain a fixed perimeter (the natural idea described by D. Carlisle).
The path is also transformed by a roundedpath routine (to smooth a little bit).

In the first version I was stupid. Here a shorter code, with the same result.

```
import hull_pi;
//    import stats;
import roundedpath;
size(10cm);

pair[] cloud;
int nbpt=55;
int depthMax=5;

// Generate random points.
for (int i=0; i < nbpt; ++i)
  cloud.push((10*unitrand(),10*unitrand()));

pair[] hull=hull(cloud,depthMin=0,depthMax=depthMax,angleMin=50,angleMax=200,3);

path s=roundedpath(polygon(hull),.1);
path snormalized=scale(40/arclength(s))*s;
draw(snormalized,blue+1bp);


pair[] cloud;
int nbpt=110;
int depthMax=10;

// Generate random points.
for (int i=0; i < nbpt; ++i)
  cloud.push((10*unitrand(),20*unitrand()));

pair[] hull=hull(cloud,depthMin=0,depthMax=depthMax,angleMin=60,angleMax=270,1);
path s=roundedpath(polygon(hull),.05);
path snormalized=scale(40/arclength(s))*s;
draw(shift(10,0)*snormalized,black+1bp);

pair[] cloud;
int nbpt=10;
int depthMax=10;

// Generate random points.
for (int i=0; i < nbpt; ++i)
  cloud.push((20*unitrand(),10*unitrand()));

pair[] hull=hull(cloud,depthMin=0,depthMax=depthMax,angleMin=60,angleMax=200,2);
path s=roundedpath(polygon(hull),.9);
path snormalized=scale(40/arclength(s))*s;
draw(shift(0,-10)*snormalized,red+1bp);
```

And the result.

[image]