# Random non erratic domain in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to draw something like this

[image]

In tikz, without being overly erratic like [Drawing random paths in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11680/drawing-random-paths-in-tikz) ?

Comment: Please post the code you've got so far. And please explain what the criteria are for something's counting as 'random' but 'non erratic'.

Comment: This is covered in the answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215927/how-to-draw-random-simple-closed-smooth-curves-but-with-the-same-perimeter)

Comment: The basic approach is to define a series of points around a circle, but randomly vary the radius (slightly), then draw a smooth (Bezier) curve through them.

Comment: @Thruston The answers there don't seem to offer a TiKZ solution, do they? (I could be mistaken - I scrolled through fairly fast.)

Comment: @cfr, true, perhaps a Tikz-guru should add one

Comment: Perhaps related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121388/random-ink-blotches-from-tikz

Answer (score 9):

Since you do not seem to require that the curves be smooth (as [How to draw random simple closed smooth curves but with the same perimeter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215927/how-to-draw-random-simple-closed-smooth-curves-but-with-the-same-perimeter) does), you can use try adjusting the parameters of `decoration=penciline` or `\freedraw`:

[image]

### References:

- `decoration=penciline` is from [Simulating hand-drawn lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39296/simulating-hand-drawn-lines): percusse
- `freedraw` is from [Simulating hand-drawn lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39296/simulating-hand-drawn-lines): Alain Matthes

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing,patterns,shapes}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39296/simulating-hand-drawn-lines: percusse
\pgfdeclaredecoration{penciline}{initial}{
    \state{initial}[width=+\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance,auto corner on length=1mm,]{
        \pgfpathcurveto%
        {% From
            \pgfqpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}
                            {\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
        }
        {%  Control 1
        \pgfmathrand
        \pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}{0pt}}
                        {\pgfqpoint{-\pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}%
                                        {\pgfmathresult\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
                        }
        }
        {%TO 
        \pgfpointadd{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast}{\pgfpoint{0.5pt}{1.5pt}}
        }
    }
    \state{final}{}
}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39296/simulating-hand-drawn-lines: Alain Matthes
\pgfdeclaredecoration{free hand}{start}
{
  \state{start}[width = +0pt,
                next state=step,
                persistent precomputation = \pgfdecoratepathhascornerstrue]{}
  \state{step}[auto end on length    = 3pt,
               auto corner on length = 3pt,               
               width=+2pt]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{
      \pgfpointadd
      {\pgfpoint{2pt}{0pt}}
      {\pgfpoint{rand*0.15pt}{rand*0.15pt}}
    }
  }
  \state{final}
  {}
}
 \tikzset{free hand/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={free hand}
    }
 } 
\def\freedraw#1;{\draw[free hand] #1;}



\begin{document}

\textbf{decoration=penciline}
\par
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (4,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (7,0);

    \begin{scope}[decoration=penciline,scale=1]
        \draw[thick, fill=blue!25, fill opacity=.25, draw=red, decorate] (A)  rectangle (2,2); 
        \draw[thick, fill=green!25, draw=brown, radius=1cm, decorate] (B)  circle ; 
        \draw[thick, fill=red!20, draw=blue, x radius=1cm, y radius=1.5cm, rotate=30, shape=circle, decorate,] (C) circle ; 
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\textbf{\textbackslash freedraw}
\par
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (4,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (7,0);

    \freedraw[thick, fill=brown!25,  draw=blue] (A)  rectangle (2,2); 
    \freedraw[thick, fill=violet!25, fill opacity=.25, draw=red] (B) circle [radius=1cm]; 
    \freedraw[thick, fill=orange!25, fill opacity=.25, draw=brown, x radius=0.15cm, y radius=1.5cm, rotate=30, shape=circle,] (C) circle {}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a *fractal* solution with *smooth lines*.

Example with two circles and two triangles:

[image: examples of fractal deformations]

The code:

```
\documentclass[convert={size=480},margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{
  fractal lineto/.style n args={2}{%
    % #1 is a ratio of length to move the middle of each segment
    % #2 is the mininum length to apply the recurrence
    to path={
      let
      \p1=(\tikztostart), % start point
      \p2=(\tikztotarget), % end point
      \n1={veclen(\x1-\x2,\y1-\y2)}, % distance 
      \p3=($(\p1)!.5!(\p2)$), % middle point
      \p4=(rand*#1*\n1,rand*#1*\n1), % random vector
      \p5=(\x3+\x4,\y3+\y4) % random moved middle point
      in \pgfextra{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\mytest{(\n1<#2)?1:0}
        \ifnum\mytest=1 %
        \tikzset{fractal lineto/.style n args={2}{line to}}
        \fi
      } to[fractal lineto={#1}{#2}] (\p5) to[fractal lineto={#1}{#2}] (\p2)
    },
  },
  % 
  fractal curveto/.style n args={4}{
    to path={
    %   % #1 is ratio of length to move the middle of each segment
    %   % #2 is the mininum length to apply the recurrence
      let
      \p0=(\tikztostart),
      \p1=(#3),
      \p2=(#4),
      \p3=(\tikztotarget),
      \p4=($(\p0)!.5!(\p1)$),
      \p5=($(\p1)!.5!(\p2)$),
      \p6=($(\p2)!.5!(\p3)$),
      \p7=($(\p4)!.5!(\p5)$),
      \p8=($(\p5)!.5!(\p6)$),
      \p9=($(\p7)!.5!(\p8)$),
      \n1={veclen(\x0-\x0,\y0-\y9)+veclen(\x9-\x3,\y9-\y3)}, % distance 
      \p{rand}=(rand*#1*\n1,rand*#1*\n1), % random vector
      \p{randang}=(rand*#1*\n1,rand*#1*\n1), % random vector
      \p{new9}=(\x9+\x{rand},\y9+\y{rand}), % random moved middle point
      \p{new7}=(\x7+\x{rand},\y7+\y{rand}), % random moved control point
      \p{new8}=(\x8+\x{rand},\y8+\y{rand}) % random moved control point
      in \pgfextra{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\mytest{(\n1<#2)?1:0}
        \ifnum\mytest=1 %
        \tikzset{
          fractal curveto/.style n args={4}{
            curve to,controls=(####3) and (####4)
          }
        }
        \fi
        %\typeout{p9:\p9}
      }
      to[fractal curveto={#1}{#2}{\p4}{\p{new7}}] (\p{new9})
      to[fractal curveto={#1}{#2}{\p{new8}}{\p{6}}] (\p3)
    },
  },
  deformation/.style n args={3}{decorate,decoration={show path construction,
      lineto code={
        \path[#3]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
        to[fractal lineto={#1}{#2}]
        (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      curveto code={
        \path[#3]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
        to[fractal curveto=%
        {#1}{#2}{\tikzinputsegmentsupporta}{\tikzinputsegmentsupportb}]
        (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      closepath code={
        \path[#3]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
        to[fractal lineto={#1}{#2}]
        (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
    },
  }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetseed{\pdfuniformdeviate 10000000}
  \def\ratio{.1}
  \def\minlen{10mm}
  \begin{scope}
    \draw[deformation={\ratio}{\minlen}{draw=red,line width=1mm}] circle(5cm);
    \draw[deformation={\ratio}{\minlen}{draw=blue,line width=1mm}] circle(5cm);
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}
    \draw[deformation={\ratio}{\minlen}{draw=lime,line width=1mm}]
    (0:4) -- (120:4) -- (-120:4) -- cycle;
    \draw[deformation={\ratio}{\minlen}{draw=orange,line width=1mm}]
    (0:4) -- (120:4) -- (-120:4) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is my contribution :

```
\documentclass[border=7mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

% create some random points arround 0
% #1 is the number of points
% #2 is the minimal radius
% #3 is the maximal deviation (if =0 no randomness)
\newcommand{\rndpts}[3]{
  \def\pts{}
  \foreach[
    evaluate=\x as \r using {#2+#3*rnd},
    evaluate=\x as \a using {\la+720*rnd/#1},
    remember=\a as \la (initially 0)]
  \x in {0,...,#1}
  {
    \pgfmathparse{int(\a)}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult > 360\relax
      \breakforeach
    \else
      \xdef\pts{\pts (\a:\r)}
    \fi
  }
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \npts/\rmin/\rdelta/\c in {10/1/2/red,20/1/3/green,30/1/4/blue,20/2/3/yellow} {
      \rndpts{\npts}{\rmin}{\rdelta}
      \draw[\c, ultra thick] plot[smooth cycle,tension=.7]  coordinates {\pts};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In all of these, there is a final non-"bendy" bit connecting the end to the beginning of the bendy bit, is there any way to remove this straight line and have bendy lines the whole way around?

Comment: @DanielWilson-Nunn good point ! I updated my answer by replacing `--cycle` with the style `smooth cycle`.